# Respond to Process Dialogs

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to code a full dialog between my app and the OS. An normal command might look something like this:

```
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {

        }
```

This gives the OS output from running the `ls` command.

However, let's say we want to run `ssh root@myserver` which will require additional input for a `password`, how can we code the input for the `password` beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

If the password is passed on the command line, then you'd pass it in when creating your process. So for instance you'd not pass in a simple String like `"ls"` but rather would pass in an array of Strings to the Runtime object (note that you should preferentially use a ProcessBuilder to get your Process, not `Runtime#exec(...)`).

If the password needs to be passed to the command line **after** the Process has been created, you would use the Process's OutputStream to pass in this data. Be careful with threading when doing this.

Note, I'm not familiar with Linux or with the `ssh root@myserver` command, and so am answering this as a community wiki so that others can either directly correct any mistakes that might be present here, or post a better answer if one is needed.

Comment: It might be useful if the community could give an example of the `ProcessBuilder` in conjunction with `OutputStream` as a thread-safe execution.

Comment: @Hooli: I have confidence in your internet search abilities, that you'll find such examples easily. You could [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+processbuilder) for instance.

Comment: Not very helpful for me or anyone else that would find this question I would assume... I find that I get prompted for a password with `ProcessBuilder` anyway, so it's not a viable route.